# How to implement the Laravel-mws library

Tags: php, laravel-5, amazon-mws, laravel-5.5

How to implement this  [Laravel-mws library](https://github.com/sonnenglas/amazon-mws-laravel)? I already followed the installation guide in the github but still it doesn't work. I also tried to run their examples in the routes still doesn't work. Someone please help me about this using laravel. Thank you.

**Code for the route**

```
<?php

use Sonnenglas\AmazonMws\AmazonOrderList;

Route::get('/', function () {
    return view('welcome');
});



Route::get('/getorders', function() {
  $amz = new AmazonOrderList("store1"); //store name matches the array key in the config file
  $amz->setLimits('Modified', "- 24 hours");
  $amz->setFulfillmentChannelFilter("MFN"); //no Amazon-fulfilled orders
  $amz->setOrderStatusFilter(
      array("Unshipped", "PartiallyShipped", "Canceled", "Unfulfillable")
      ); //no shipped or pending
  $amz->setUseToken(); //Amazon sends orders 100 at a time, but we want them all
  $amz->fetchOrders();
  return $amz->getList();
});
```

Comment: What you have tried? What errors you are getting? Show your code

Comment: I don't have an error but it only display `[ ]` I will update the question I'll add the code. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I know it's been a while, but I recently fixed this issue in [my fork of that package](https://github.com/keithbrink/amazon-mws-laravel).

The issue is that you can't have the root marketplaceId AND the marketplaceId.Id.1 parameter set. If you want to fix it yourself, just add `unset($this->options['marketplaceId']);` somewhere before the call is sent to Amazon, such as the constructor of `AmazonOrderList.php`.